# Best practise: Window Phone, how to sync files with a server

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, synchronization

I am going to write some apps on WP 7.5 in C#, which should store some user input in files, and later on these files should be synced with a server.

However, internet connection might not always be available. 
So, the app should store the data inernally first, and later on it should synchronize with the server in the background.

Now, is a background sync possible at all? If yes, are there any prebuilt-functionalities to do this? Or else, what is the 'best practice' to do such sychronizing tasks ?

Our file server's protocol can be chosen according to this task. We could even use a SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about "Background file transfers for Windows Phone":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx

Especially read and understand the policies and constraints regarding data size, duration, etc.

Note that this topic is part of the broader topic 'Multitasking for Windows Phone' which includes the background file transfers, tasks, etc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202866(v=vs.105).aspx